# Nowjs still not working with express 3.0

Tags: node.js, express, nowjs-sockets

I`m trying to get nowjs to work with express 3.0 just like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782832/nowjs-expressjs-3-0) question. I am following the code but I still get "Now is not defined".

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 in an Oracle VM virtual box.

First I create an express app.

```
$ express myBrilliantNewApp
```

Then I install nowjs in the new dir.

```
$ sudo npm install now
```

Add the server variable and use it with now.

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
})

var everyone = require('now').initialize(server);
```

Then I should be able to do this...

```
everyone.now.writesomething = function() {
console.log('I would really like it if this shows up at the console') 
};
```

...and make the call and check what everyone is all about.

```
now.writesomething();
console.log(everyone);
```

It does not work. I get:

```
[ReferenceError: now is not defined]
ReferenceError: now is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jan/dev/apps/probeer1/app.js:44:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Full listing app.js

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
})

var everyone = require('now').initialize(server);


everyone.now.writesomething = function() {
  console.log('I would really like it if this shows up at the console')
};

now.writesomething();
console.log(everyone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using nowjs on the server you need to call:

```
var nowjs = require('now');
```

To use nowjs on the client you need to include a script reference in your HTML:

```
<script src="/nowjs/now.js"></script>
```

Comment: thnx, my bad when tinkering with the code I forgot. Put it back in. Same (kind of) problem however

Comment: Did you include the now.js script reference on the client side?  See updated answer.

Comment: I tried to make a clean reproduction of the error, calling a function from server side. See updated question. Should this work?

Comment: Also tried a client side call (now.js reference included). Now.js script loads. I get the error "now.writesomething is not a function" in the client console.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer for details: [Cannot find module 'now' - nowjs and nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857409/cannot-find-module-now-nowjs-and-nodejs)

```
npm config set global true && \
     echo 'export NODE_PATH="'$(npm root -g)'"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
     . ~/.bashrc
```

Try again with global flag

```
sudo npm install now -g
```

Comment: This seems indeed to be the problem although NODE_PATH variable seems ok. echo $NODE_PATH => /usr/local/lib/node_modules. Problem persists. I get, Checking for node path : not found, when installing with npm. I get the same error when trying dnode for example.

Comment: I have tried both global and local already. Doesn't work. Maybe something with the user scope of the NODE_PATH env variable?